# How to add Item in Dropdown list in cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

**This is my CS file for dropdown:**

```
protected void BindDropDownList()     

    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EyeProject"];
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT FirstName FROM tbl_UserDetails";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataSource =dt;


                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FirstName"; // the items to be displayed in the list items

                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "No Data Found To display in the DropDown List";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }


    }



By using this one iam getting values of table Firstname values now i want to add one more item Called ALLrecords. 

How can i add it.

this is my Aspx file 

 <div class="label">
                                    Select Name:
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("All Record"));
```

and if you want to add item with value then

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("All Record","0"));

 //or if you want to add at particular index then

 DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("All Record"));// 0 is index of item
```

hope this helps.

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("All Record")); iam using this one .after displaying allcords in dropdown the remaining values what ever iam geting from database i.e., firstname .It also have to show in dropdown when i click it.

Comment: First bind dropdown with your database values as you done right now and then use Add or insert method which you suitable.

Answer (score 3):

insert an item at specified index

```
DropDownListID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Default text", "Default value")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("AllRecords","itsValue_on_dropdownlist")); // use 0 to show "ALLRecords" text on top in dropdownlist
```

i would suggest that you should bind values to dropdownlist also.
like this -

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FirstName";
```

Answer (score 0):

First write onLoad with "addItems" function in dropdownlist declaring tag .aspx file like this:

then create "addItems" function in cs file.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnLoad="addDeleteItems" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">

protected void addItems(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;           
     ListItem newItem = new ListItem("rose", "i");
     ddl.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```